# Why is 'a' displayed as 40 in ouput?

Tags: c

```
int a;
int *p=&a;
a = 20;
*p = 40;
printf("%d",a);
```

Output:
40

Can anyone explain why the output is 40?

Answer (score 2):

Lets draw it out:

```
+---+     +---+
| p | --> | a |
+---+     +---+
```

That is, the variable `p` points to the variable `a`.

When you use `*p` you follow the pointer to get `a`.

So `*p = 40` is equivalent to `a = 40`.

Answer (score 0):

In this code, the `a` variable is declared as an `int`, and it is initialized with the value 20. A pointer `p` is then declared, and it is initialized with the address of the `a` variable.

Next, the value of the `a` variable is modified by using the pointer `p`. The `*` operator is used to dereference the pointer, which means that it gives us the value stored at the address that the pointer points to. In this case, the pointer `p` points to the `a` variable, so when we dereference `p` and assign the value 40 to it, we are effectively assigning the value 40 to the `a` variable.

Since the value of the `a` variable was previously set to 40 using the pointer, the output of the `printf` statement is 40.

The output is 40 because the pointer is used to modify the value of the `a` variable, and the `printf` statement prints the modified value of `a`.